# Change dirname where Babel 6 looks for plugins and transforms

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using babel via babel-loader for Webpack from an external CLI Node.JS tool to the project I'm compiling. This means that in our case, transformas and plugins should be looked for in `__dirname` rather than in `process.cwd()` which is the default that [babel uses](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-core/src/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js#L191).

That code in babel is part of a function that accepts a `dirname` parameter, but none of the calls to the function set it, so it's always `process.cwd()` and I can't find a way to override it from babel-loader.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I've missed some config option.

Thanks!